# Recursive Power Function Sanity Check

Tags: c++, recursion, math

This is kind of an unusual question, but I'm working a problem and my issue is that it's working. But only when I run it, not when it's put through the submit process. I wrote this function to handle exponents using recursion (the requirement of the problem).

```
double Pow(double num, int power) {  
   if (num == 1.0 || power == 0){
      return 1.0;
   } else if ( power > 0){
      return (num * Pow( num, power - 1 ) );
   } else{
      return ( (1.0/num) * Pow( num, power + 1 ) );
   } 
}
```

When I submit the code it fails every unit test. When manually input the values used in the unit tests it produces the correct output, so I have no idea what I need to fix. Is there an error in my logic I'm not seeing here?

(The unit tests it's failing are -10^-3 and -10^-4)

EDIT- For clarity here is exactly what is shown after submission:

```
Test -10.0 -4
Test feedback: Your function did not return 0.0001

Test -10.0 -3
Test feedback: Your function did not return -0.001
```

It does not tell me what the function did return, nor can I see how the unit tests are conducted. The real problem is when I attempt to reproduce the failure, I get the correct output (by hard coding a function call of Pow(-10.0,-4) and Pow(-10.0, -3) )

EDIT 2- The solution was found below. Rounding error was the culprit.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How is the checkings in the unit tests performed? Do they allow some errors?

Comment: Show your unit tests, along with the incorrect results you get.

Comment: That's part of my issue unfortunately. I'm working with zybooks, and there is no transparency for how the unit test is performed. The submission sections conducts 3 tests. The first uses hard coded values provided in the main function (literally just a call to the function I provided and a cout of the result). The second and third are just labeled "unit tests" and only state the units provided, and "your function did not return <answer>". It does not tell you what answer your function did produce. It's frustratingly opaque. For reference my function passes the test using hard coded input.

Comment: I don't know this testing tool, but isn't there some kind of logging that catches `cout`, `printf` or other output results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return ( (1.0/num) * Pow( num, power + 1 ) );` contains an unnecessary rounding because `1.0/num` produces the result of `1` / `num` rounded to the nearest representable value, and this is then multiplied by `Pow(num, power+1)`.

Change this to `return Pow(num, power+1) / num;`. This eliminates the extra rounding. In the two cases you show, this results in values identical to what the test expects.

(In spite of this improvement, floating-point arithmetic is subject to rounding errors that may produce additional differences between what is computed and what the test expects, depending on the design of the test.)

Comment: Thanks, after this change the unit tests were marked correct, and as I bonus I learned something about rounding errors. Appreciate the help.